# Do I really need the parameters in this stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

The following stored procedure is intended to grab all the BLOB values from an Oracle database and save them into a folder called OraFolder.

It compiles fine but I have 2 questions.

1, there are 2 parameters, pname and display_name. I must admit that I don't know what they are there for because I just googled the code which seems to fit into our need.

My question is do I really need the 2 params given that we are trying to extract ALL BLOB values into a folder?

2, If your answer is yes, I do need them, how I do I use them?

Finally, there is an Entry_Id, I just kept getting an error that it is not declared. I had to remove it. What is it used for?

Sorr, I am not an Oracle guy, just trying to figure out a wa to fix a problem that is dropped on my laps.

Thanks in advance

Here is the complete stored proc.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE blob2file(pfname VARCHAR2, display_name in varchar2) IS



vblob BLOB;
vstart NUMBER := 1;
bytelen NUMBER := 32000;
len NUMBER;
my_vr RAW(32000);
x NUMBER;
v_name varchar2(100);
lv_str_len NUMBER;
l_output utl_file.file_type;



BEGIN
-- define output directory
lv_str_len := length(pfname);
--v_name := display_name||upper(substr(pfname,lv_str_len-3,lv_str_len));
v_name := display_name;
l_output := utl_file.fopen('MY_FOLDER', v_name, 'w', 32760);



-- get length of blob
SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(blob_content)
INTO len
FROM portal.WWDOC_DOCUMENT$
WHERE FILENAME = pfname;


-- dbms_output.put_line('Length: '||len);
-- save blob length
x := len;



-- select blob into variable
SELECT blob_content
INTO vblob
FROM portal.WWDOC_DOCUMENT$
WHERE FILENAME = pfname;



-- if small enough for a single write
IF len < 32760 THEN
-- dbms_output.put_line('Single write ');
utl_file.put_raw(l_output,vblob);
utl_file.fflush(l_output);
ELSE -- write in pieces
-- dbms_output.put_line('multi write '||vstart);
vstart := 1;
WHILE vstart < len
LOOP

dbms_lob.read(vblob,bytelen,vstart,my_vr);



utl_file.put_raw(l_output,my_vr);
utl_file.fflush(l_output);



-- set the start position for the next cut
vstart := vstart + bytelen;



-- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
x := x - bytelen;
IF x < 32000 THEN
bytelen := x;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END IF;
dbms_output.put_line('End');
utl_file.fclose(l_output);
EXCEPTION
when others then dbms_output.put_line('ERROR:'||entry_id);
END blob2file;
```

Comment: I am assuming this is the hacked up one you got to compile.  PL is a turing complete language with all the same rules as other languages based on ADA.  Please show me the original SP and I will see what I can do.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have replaced the code posted with the original you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pfname` param defines which file to grab, so you don't need that since you want them all.

The `display_name` param defines the output directory, so if you want to hard code the directory, you could.

Since you want all files, you'll need to loop through all records in the table and output them one at a time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE blob2file 
IS
   l_output    utl_file.file_type;
   vstart      NUMBER := 1;
   bytelen     NUMBER := 32000;
   x           NUMBER;
   my_vr       RAW(32000);
BEGIN

   FOR recFiles IN (SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(BLOB_CONTENT) as len,
                           FILENAME,
                           BLOB_CONTENT
                      FROM PORTAL.WWDOC_DOCUMENT$)
   LOOP

      l_output := utl_file.fopen('MY_FOLDER', '/hard code the path here/', 'w', 32760);

      IF recFiles.len < 32760 THEN

         utl_file.put_raw(l_output, recFiles.BLOB_CONTENT);
         utl_file.fflush(l_output);

      ELSE -- write in pieces

         vstart := 1;

         WHILE vstart < refFiles.len
         LOOP
            dbms_lob.read(recFiles.BLOB_CONTENT, bytelen, vstart, my_vr);
            utl_file.put_raw(l_output, my_vr);
            utl_file.fflush(l_output);

            -- set the start position for the next cut
            vstart := vstart + bytelen;

            -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
            x := x - bytelen;

            IF x < 32000 THEN
               bytelen := x;
            END IF;

         END LOOP;

      END IF;

      utl_file.fclose(l_output);
      dbms_output.put_line('End');

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: ' || SQLERRM);

END blob2file;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Experts, I had my version of the code working. I was able to extract a couple of files from the database to the folder specified. All looked good. However, after the 2 files were successfuly extracted, each attempt to extract any other file would result to an error that says, "invalid hex number" I can't wrap my head around this error. My goal was to ensure that my was working correctly, then I would use this nice solution by wweiker to extract all teh files but it isn't working well so far. Can you please help?

Comment: @Kenny Can you post the error details? Line number, exception message... and where is the error happening, in my code or in your original code, or an amalgamation of them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `vname` is the name of the file which the blob is written to. And `pname` is the key of the blob in the table. So if you're dumping all blobs in the table then you don't need either of these, but you will need to come up with a unique filename for each blob.